# How to delete all smallest numbers in doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a function that deletes the smallest node in a doubly-linked list. But if there are more than one same-valued integers, the function deletes the first one. I need to do, that function deletes all the smallest values.

I think I need to make a loop, to check all the values in the linked list and delete them if they are == to the smallest one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    struct node *prev;
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *createList(struct node *head, int n);
node *addToEmpty(node *head, int data);
node *addAtEnd(node *head, int data);
node *deleteSmallest(node *head, int n);
void cleanUp(node *head);

int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node *ptr;
    int n;

    printf("Enter number of the nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    head = createList(head, n);
    printf("\nN: %d\n\n", n);

    ptr = head;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("NUMBER:%d ADDRESS:%p PREVADD:%p NEXTADD:%p\n", ptr->number, ptr, ptr->prev, ptr->next);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    head = deleteSmallest(head, n);

    printf("\n\n");

    ptr = head;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("NUMBER:%d ADDRESS:%p PREVADD:%p NEXTADD:%p\n", ptr->number, ptr, ptr->prev, ptr->next);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    // Free all the pointers
    cleanUp(head);

    return 0;
}

node *createList(struct node *head, int n)
{
    int data;

    if(n <= 0)
        return head;

    printf("Enter number of the 1 node: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);

    head = addToEmpty(head, data);

    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter number of the %d node: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        head = addAtEnd(head, data);
    }
    return head;
}

node *addToEmpty(node *head, int data)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->number = data;
    head = temp;

    return head;
}

node *addAtEnd(node *head, int data)
{
    node *temp, *tp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->number = data;
    tp = head;

    while (tp->next != NULL)
        tp = tp->next;

    tp->next = temp;
    temp->prev = tp;

    return head;
}

node *deleteSmallest(node *head, int n)
{
    node *smallest, *temp, *temporaryHead;
    int position = 1;
    temporaryHead = head;
    smallest = head;

    // Finding which node has the smallest int
    for(int i = 1; temporaryHead != NULL; ++i)
    {
        temp = temporaryHead->next;
        if(smallest->number > temporaryHead->number)
        {
            smallest = temporaryHead;
            position = i;
        }
        temporaryHead = temp;
    }

    temporaryHead = NULL;

    temp = head;

    // If node is in the middle
    if(position > 1 && position < n)
    {
        while (position > 1) {
            temp = temp->next;
            --position;
        }
        temporaryHead = temp->prev;
        temporaryHead->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->prev = temporaryHead;
        free(temp);
        temp = NULL;
    }else if(position == 1)             // If node is the first element
    {
        head = head->next;
        free(head->prev);
        head->prev = NULL;
    }else                               // If node is the last element
    {
        while(temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        temporaryHead = temp->prev;
        temporaryHead->next = NULL;
        free(temp);
        temp = NULL;
    }

    return head;
}

void cleanUp(node *head)
{
    node *next;

    while(head != NULL)
    {
        next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask a specific question.

Comment: There is not much point having a doubly linked list if you always need to start from one end. (That can be fixed either by maintaining a reference to the tail end of the list, or by implementing it as a circular list.)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  If removing the smallest element is a common operation, then a doubly linked list is (probably) the wrong data structure to be using.

Comment: Perhaps a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) would be better suited to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I need to make a loop, to check all the values in the linked list and delete them if they are == to the smallest one.

I didn't quite understand the logic of your current function (particularly, the `n` argument).

Here is a function that will allow just one element to be removed or *all* matching smallest elements. If there is *only* one it is a single scan pass. If there are more, it is just two scan passes:

```
// deleteSmallAll -- delete all nodes that are the smallest
node *
deleteSmallAll(node *head,int allflg)
// allflg -- 1=delete all, 0=delete first
{
    node *small = head;
    int smcount = 0;
    int smnum = 0;
    node *cur = head;

    // skip over the first element (and assume it is the smallest)
    if (cur != NULL) {
        cur = cur->next;
        smcount = 1;
        smnum = small->number;
    }

    // find the smallest
    for (;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
        int curnum = cur->number;

        // got a smaller element
        if (curnum < smnum) {
            smcount = 1;
            small = cur;
            smnum = curnum;
            continue;
        }

        // keep count of duplicate small numbers
        if (curnum == smnum) {
            if (allflg)
                smcount += 1;
            continue;
        }
    }

    // start with the _first_ smallest node we found
    cur = small;

    // remove a single smallest and loop if more to do
    while (cur != NULL) {
        node *next = cur->next;
        node *prev = cur->prev;

        // unlink it
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = next;
        else
            head = next;

        // unlink it
        if (next != NULL)
            next->prev = prev;
// NOTE: no tail pointer
#if 0
        else
            tail = prev;
#endif

        // release the node
        free(cur);

        // bug out if no more of that match
        if (--smcount <= 0)
            break;

        // find the next in the list that is the same match
        for (cur = next;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
            if (cur->number == smnum)
                break;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Hopefully, you've gotten an answer for your basic question.

But, as others pointed out, what's the point to have a *doubly* linked list if you *only* traverse it in the forward direction?

Below is an updated version. It uses a separate `list` struct and passes a pointer to that instead of passing in `head` and always returning the updated value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *prev;
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct {
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} list;

int
getnum(const char *prompt)
{
    char buf[100];
    int data = 0;

    // debug hook for input from redirected file (e.g. ./myprogram < input.txt)
    struct termios tio;
    int fileflg = tcgetattr(fileno(stdin),&tio) < 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("%s: ",prompt);
        fflush(stdout);

        if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) == NULL) {
            printf("getnum: premature EOF\n");
            if (fileflg)
                exit(1);
        }

        // echo the file input
        if (fileflg)
            fputs(buf,stdout);

        if (sscanf(buf,"%d",&data) == 1)
            break;
    }

    return data;
}

void
addAtEnd(list *lst, int data)
{
    node *temp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->number = data;

    if (lst->head == NULL)
        lst->head = temp;

    node *tail = lst->tail;
    if (tail != NULL) {
        temp->next = tail->next;
        tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = tail;
    }
    else
        temp->prev = NULL;

    lst->tail = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
}

void
createList(list *lst, int n)
{
    int data;
    char msg[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sprintf(msg,"Enter number of the %d node", i + 1);
        data = getnum(msg);
        addAtEnd(lst, data);
    }
}

// deleteSmallAll -- delete all nodes that are the smallest
void
deleteSmallAll(list *lst,int allflg)
// allflg -- 1=delete all, 0=delete first
{
    node *small = lst->head;
    int smcount = 0;
    int smnum = 0;
    node *cur = lst->head;

    // skip over the first element (and assume it is the smallest)
    if (cur != NULL) {
        smcount = 1;
        smnum = small->number;
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    // find the smallest
    for (;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
        int curnum = cur->number;

        // got a smaller element
        if (curnum < smnum) {
            smcount = 1;
            small = cur;
            smnum = curnum;
            continue;
        }

        // keep count of duplicate small numbers
        if (curnum == smnum) {
            if (allflg)
                smcount += 1;
            continue;
        }
    }

    // start with the _first_ smallest node we found
    cur = small;

    // remove a single smallest and loop if more to do
    while (cur != NULL) {
        node *next = cur->next;
        node *prev = cur->prev;

        // unlink it
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = next;
        else
            lst->head = next;

        // unlink it
        if (next != NULL)
            next->prev = prev;
        else
            lst->tail = prev;

        // release the node
        free(cur);

        // bug out if no more of that match
        if (--smcount <= 0)
            break;

        // find the next in the list that is the same match
        for (cur = next;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
            if (cur->number == smnum)
                break;
        }
    }
}

void
cleanUp(list *lst)
{
    node *next;

    for (node *cur = lst->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        next = cur->next;
        free(cur);
    }

    lst->head = NULL;
    lst->tail = NULL;
}

void
print_fwd(list *lst,const char *msg)
{
    node *ptr = lst->head;

    printf("\n%s:\n",msg);
    for (;  ptr != NULL;  ptr = ptr->next)
        printf("NUMBER:%d ADDRESS:%p PREVADD:%p NEXTADD:%p\n",
            ptr->number, ptr, ptr->prev, ptr->next);
}

void
print_bwd(list *lst,const char *msg)
{
    node *ptr = lst->tail;

    printf("\n%s:\n",msg);
    for (;  ptr != NULL;  ptr = ptr->prev)
        printf("NUMBER:%d ADDRESS:%p PREVADD:%p NEXTADD:%p\n",
            ptr->number, ptr, ptr->prev, ptr->next);
}

int
main(void)
{
    list lstx = { NULL, NULL };
    list *lst = &lstx;
    node *ptr;
    int n;

    n = getnum("Enter number of the nodes");

    createList(lst, n);
    printf("\nN: %d\n", n);
    print_fwd(lst,"orig/fwd");
    print_bwd(lst,"orig/bwd");

    deleteSmallAll(lst, 0);
    print_fwd(lst,"after1/fwd");
    print_bwd(lst,"after1/bwd");

    deleteSmallAll(lst, 1);
    print_fwd(lst,"afterN/fwd");
    print_bwd(lst,"afterN/bwd");

    // Free all the pointers
    cleanUp(lst);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the sample input:

```
6
2
6
2
7
8
2
```

Here is the sample output:

```
Enter number of the nodes: 6
Enter number of the 1 node: 2
Enter number of the 2 node: 6
Enter number of the 3 node: 2
Enter number of the 4 node: 7
Enter number of the 5 node: 8
Enter number of the 6 node: 2

N: 6

orig/fwd:
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a4280 PREVADD:(nil) NEXTADD:0x11a42a0
NUMBER:6 ADDRESS:0x11a42a0 PREVADD:0x11a4280 NEXTADD:0x11a42c0
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a42c0 PREVADD:0x11a42a0 NEXTADD:0x11a42e0
NUMBER:7 ADDRESS:0x11a42e0 PREVADD:0x11a42c0 NEXTADD:0x11a4300
NUMBER:8 ADDRESS:0x11a4300 PREVADD:0x11a42e0 NEXTADD:0x11a4320
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a4320 PREVADD:0x11a4300 NEXTADD:(nil)

orig/bwd:
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a4320 PREVADD:0x11a4300 NEXTADD:(nil)
NUMBER:8 ADDRESS:0x11a4300 PREVADD:0x11a42e0 NEXTADD:0x11a4320
NUMBER:7 ADDRESS:0x11a42e0 PREVADD:0x11a42c0 NEXTADD:0x11a4300
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a42c0 PREVADD:0x11a42a0 NEXTADD:0x11a42e0
NUMBER:6 ADDRESS:0x11a42a0 PREVADD:0x11a4280 NEXTADD:0x11a42c0
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a4280 PREVADD:(nil) NEXTADD:0x11a42a0

after1/fwd:
NUMBER:6 ADDRESS:0x11a42a0 PREVADD:(nil) NEXTADD:0x11a42c0
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a42c0 PREVADD:0x11a42a0 NEXTADD:0x11a42e0
NUMBER:7 ADDRESS:0x11a42e0 PREVADD:0x11a42c0 NEXTADD:0x11a4300
NUMBER:8 ADDRESS:0x11a4300 PREVADD:0x11a42e0 NEXTADD:0x11a4320
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a4320 PREVADD:0x11a4300 NEXTADD:(nil)

after1/bwd:
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a4320 PREVADD:0x11a4300 NEXTADD:(nil)
NUMBER:8 ADDRESS:0x11a4300 PREVADD:0x11a42e0 NEXTADD:0x11a4320
NUMBER:7 ADDRESS:0x11a42e0 PREVADD:0x11a42c0 NEXTADD:0x11a4300
NUMBER:2 ADDRESS:0x11a42c0 PREVADD:0x11a42a0 NEXTADD:0x11a42e0
NUMBER:6 ADDRESS:0x11a42a0 PREVADD:(nil) NEXTADD:0x11a42c0

afterN/fwd:
NUMBER:6 ADDRESS:0x11a42a0 PREVADD:(nil) NEXTADD:0x11a42e0
NUMBER:7 ADDRESS:0x11a42e0 PREVADD:0x11a42a0 NEXTADD:0x11a4300
NUMBER:8 ADDRESS:0x11a4300 PREVADD:0x11a42e0 NEXTADD:(nil)

afterN/bwd:
NUMBER:8 ADDRESS:0x11a4300 PREVADD:0x11a42e0 NEXTADD:(nil)
NUMBER:7 ADDRESS:0x11a42e0 PREVADD:0x11a42a0 NEXTADD:0x11a4300
NUMBER:6 ADDRESS:0x11a42a0 PREVADD:(nil) NEXTADD:0x11a42e0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the logic into parts:

- A function to find the least *value* (an integer) in a list
- A function to delete nodes from a list that have a given value
- Use the above two functions to implement `deleteSmallest`

Here is how that could look:

```
int getSmallestValue(node *head) {
    int smallest = head == NULL ? 0 : head->number;
    while (head != NULL) {
        if (head->number < smallest) {
            smallest = head->number;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    return smallest;
}

node* deleteValue(node *head, int n) {
    node* temp, *current;
    while (head != NULL && head->number == n) {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    head->prev = NULL;
    current = head->next;
    while (current != NULL) {
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;
        if (temp->number == n) {
            temp->prev->next = current;
            if (current != NULL) {
                current->prev = temp->prev;
            }
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    return head;
}

node *deleteSmallest(node *head, int n) {
    return deleteValues(head, getSmallestValue(head));
}
```

Comment: Too bad you removed the acceptance mark ;-) I still think this is an elegant way to deal with the problem (splitting into separate functions, which each are useful on their own). If there was an issue, will you let me know?

Answer (score 0):

If you were concerned about performance, instead of `addAtEnd()`, you might have `addToFront()`. This would reduce the asymptotic time from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` to input the numbers.

If you must delete-minimum again and again, a linked-list is not really a good fit. As you have observed, all the input must be traversed if one wants to find the minimum, which takes `O(n)` each time. In this case, a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) would allow `O(log n)` delete-minimum. It does this by `heapify`, in which the heap is created by sifting down in `O(n)`, and maintaining the heap property of each `int` is less than or equal to the `int`'s children.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void int_to_string(const int *i, char (*const a)[12])
    { sprintf(*a, "%d", *i); }

#define HEAP_NAME int
#define HEAP_TYPE int
#define HEAP_TO_STRING
#include "heap.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct int_heap ints = int_heap();
    size_t n = 0;
    int success = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    (void)argc; /* Don't use. */
    while(*++argv) { /* Get command line arguments. */
        long argl;
        char *end;
        int *a;
        argl = strtol(*argv, &end, 0); /* Convert to `long`. */
        if(argl < INT_MIN || argl > INT_MAX || end == *argv || *end != '\0')
            { if(!errno) errno = ERANGE; goto catch; }
        if(!(a = int_heap_buffer(&ints, n + 1))) goto catch;
        a[n++] = (int)argl;
    }
    int_heap_append(&ints, n); /* Heapifies, O(n), <Floyd, 1964, Treesort>. */
    while(ints.as_array.size) printf("pop: %d, remainder: %s\n",
        int_heap_pop(&ints), int_heap_to_string(&ints));
    printf("empty\n");
    goto finally;
catch:
    success = EXIT_FAILURE;
    perror("count");
finally:
    int_heap_(&ints);
    return success;
}
```

I have used my [implementation of a binary heap](https://github.com/neil-edelman/heap), which I've tried to make pretty standard. This is close to what [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) does.